# On click open the calendar component and elsewhere click should close the component

Tags: reactjs

I have a calendar component which should be opened on the click of the input field. I have written a function search() for that. But sometimes it works properly, sometimes it gives the error.

```
searchClick = (data) => {
        if (data == "start") {
            if (!this.state.isCalendar) {
                document.addEventListener('click', this.closeStart, true);
            }
            else {
                document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeStart, true);
            }
            this.setState(prevState => ({ isCalendar: !prevState.isCalendar }),()=>console.log(this.state.isCalendar));
        }
        else {
            if (!this.state.isCalendarNext) {
                document.addEventListener('click', this.closeEnd, false);
            } else {
                document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeEnd, false);
            }
            this.setState(prevState => ({ isCalendarNext: !prevState.isCalendarNext }));
        }
    }



closeStart = (e) => {
        if (this.searchNode != null && this.searchNodeCalendar != null) {
            if (this.searchNode.contains(e.target) || this.searchNodeCalendar.contains(e.target)) {
                return;
            }
            this.searchClick("start");
        }
    }



    closeEnd = (e) => {
        if (this.searchEndNode != null && this.searchNodeCalendarNext != null) {
            if (this.searchEndNode.contains(e.target) || this.searchNodeCalendarNext.contains(e.target)) {
                return;
            }
            this.searchClick("end");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the error you have ?

Comment: parse-time.js:41 Uncaught Error: Could not parse time (string)
    at parseTime (parse-time.js:41)
    at RadiumEnhancer.Timepicker (Timepicker.js:152)
    at new RadiumEnhancer (enhancer.js:189)
    at constructClassInstance (react-dom.development.js:11787)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:15265)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:16265)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:20285)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:20326)

Comment: I have two input fields for start date and end date. On click of any of these, respective calendar should open and if user click on body or else where, calendar should close.

Comment: My code works fine. But sometimes, I'm getting this error in console and blank page.